# React 'this' is undefined in Chrome developer tools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, this

When I inspect my React code in the Chrome developer tools 'Source' tab, and I hover over the 'this.props' or even 'this' keyword / add it to watches, it shows up as undefined. Even though the code referred to executes successfully. Very annoying.... is this is bug? Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: Please post text; code is text. *(Unless you're programming in Piet/etc.)* (And image is fine as *additional* information. Although I'd probably include a bit of surrounding code so we can see the complete context.)

Answer (score 8):

It's `undefined` because you're inside an arrow function and by definition an arrow function doesn't own a context but it inherits the enclosing one.

If you check the menu on the right handside and scroll down to the current scope you will find the closure chain of that function (one of which in your case will be the component class) that has the `this` inherited by your function.

e.g.

[image]

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
> enclosing lexical scope is used;

[Arrow functions doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)

Answer (score 3):

Due to how lexical `this` is treated by Babel in arrow functions, it cannot be `this` inside an arrow. Temporary variables like `_this`, `_this2`, etc. are used to imitate lexical `this` in ES5.

Transpiled code looks like:

```
var _this = this;
...
.then(function () {
  ...
  _this.setState(...);
});
```

Even though it appears like original ES6 source in debugger because of sourcemaps, it's ES5 that is evaluated. So it's `_this` local variable that needs to be debugged.